# Azure Terraform provider based on environment

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have 3 Azure subscriptions one for each environment (lab,dev,production). As of now i am using environment specific Terraform variables using variables.auto.tfvars

```
--terrform-project
  |__confg
       |_lab
           |_variables.tfvars
       |_dev
           |_variables.tfvars
       |_production
           |_variables.tfvars
  main.tf
  variables.tf
```

In my CI/CD pipeline, for the Terraform Cloud workspace, i do cp /config//variables.tf /config//variables.auto.tfvars so i am able to read variables appropriately.

However, i have provider section in variables.tf, because of this i am running to errors such as resource not found errors because of invalid provider subscription. What is the best way to have different providers based on the environment instead of handling this below approach?

```
in variables.tf
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.21.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  alias                      = "dev-sub"
  subscription_id            = var.subscriptionId
  client_id                  = var.client_id
  client_secret              = var.client_secret
  tenant_id                  = var.tenant_id
  skip_provider_registration = true
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias                      = "poc-sub"
  subscription_id            = var.subscriptionId
  client_id                  = var.client_id
  client_secret              = var.client_secret
  tenant_id                  = var.tenant_id
  skip_provider_registration = true
  features {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  alias                      = "prod-sub"
  subscription_id            = var.subscriptionId
  client_id                  = var.client_id
  client_secret              = var.client_secret
  tenant_id                  = var.tenant_id
  skip_provider_registration = true
}

in main.tf
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "container" {
  provider              = azurerm.poc-sub
  name                  = "file"
  storage_account_name  = local.storageAccountName
  container_access_type = "private"
}
```

I have tried hard coding `poc-sub`  subscription in main.tf but within CI/CD i am doing this to replace the subscription

```
if [[ ${environment} == "prod" ]]; then
                        provider_info='azurerm.prod-sub'
                    elif [[ ${environment} == "dev" ]]; then
                        provider_info='azurerm.dev-sub'
                    else
                        provider_info='azurerm.poc-sub'
                    fi
                    sed -i "s|azurerm.poc-sub|${provider_info}|g" $WORKSPACE/terrform-project/main.tf
```

Answer (score 0):

> Handling different environments in a Terraform setup can indeed be tricky. Your current setup involving copying variable files and using `sed` to replace strings in your `main.tf` is a bit cumbersome and prone to errors.

When using Terraform, it is ideal to avoid hardcoding and manual replacements as much as possible, and instead leverage the dynamic features of Terraform to manage environment-specific configurations. One way to solve this is by utilizing the Terraform `workspaces` feature combined with dynamic provider selection based on the workspace name, which can represent the environment.

It would be advantageous to utilize Terraform workspaces to manage different environments. Here’s how you could structure your files and set up your configuration based on the information provided

```
--terraform-project
  |__config
  |   |_variables.tf
  |
  |__main.tf
  |
  |__providers.tf
```

**Terraform configuration:**

##### config/variables.tf:

```
variable "subscription_id" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    lab   = "lab-subscription-id"
    dev   = "dev-subscription-id"
    prod  = "prod-subscription-id"
  }
}

variable "client_id" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    lab   = "lab-client-id"
    dev   = "dev-client-id"
    prod  = "prod-client-id"
  }
}

variable "client_secret" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    lab   = "lab-client-secret"
    dev   = "dev-client-secret"
    prod  = "prod-client-secret"
  }
}

variable "tenant_id" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    lab   = "lab-tenant-id"
    dev   = "dev-tenant-id"
    prod  = "prod-tenant-id"
  }
}
```

##### providers.tf:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  alias                      = terraform.workspace
  subscription_id            = var.subscription_id[terraform.workspace]
  client_id                  = var.client_id[terraform.workspace]
  client_secret              = var.client_secret[terraform.workspace]
  tenant_id                  = var.tenant_id[terraform.workspace]
  skip_provider_registration = true
}
```

**main.tf:**

```
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "container" {
  provider              = azurerm
  name                  = "file"
  storage_account_name  = local.storageAccountName
  container_access_type = "private"
}
```

This setup simplifies the management of different environments by leveraging Terraform workspaces and a single provider configuration that dynamically references workspace-specific variables.

1. Ensure that the correct workspace is selected before running Terraform commands. You can do this with the command `terraform workspace select {workspace-name}`.
2. Run `terraform init` and `terraform apply` as usual, and Terraform will use the appropriate variables and provider configuration based on the selected workspace.